# How to say "If you were to go to Korea, where would you like to visit?"

Tags: translation

It's a weird question, but how would you go about asking someone "If you were to go to korea, where would you visit first?"
I mean it in a context of, if you were talking to someone who has never been to Korea before, and want to know the first place they'd visit e.g. tourist attractions how would you say this?

Comment: There are [several speech levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_speech_levels). Will the listener be your close friends at your age or someone else?

Comment: it is for a book, they will be my close friend in said book

Answer (score 1):

You who is **not in Korea** can tell the following to your close friends who are **at your age (or near your age)**:

> (만약) 한국에 간다면 (거기서) 어디를 먼저 가 보고 싶어?

which literally means: "If you (happen to) go to Korea, where would you like to try going first (there)?" This sentence can be used regardless of whether they have ever been to Korea. You should note that this is just one way. You can use 만일 instead of 만약, 어디로 or 어디에 instead of 어디를, 제일 먼저 or 가장 먼저 instead of 먼저, 먼저 어디를 instead of 어디를 먼저, and 가고 instead of 가 보고. You may ask other Koreans for more advanced sentences. Some will use 방문하다 to translate "to visit," but this verb is not so common in casual conversation.

On a side note, I would say the following because I am **in Korea**:

> (살면서) 한국에 올 일이 생긴다면 어딜 먼저 가 볼래?